# run connectedAndroidTest with existing build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, continuous-integration

I am building and testing an app in a CI environment and want to use the Android Gradle Plugin's connectedAndroidTest task to run tests in parallel on multiple devices because it is convenient and gives a test report after all testing is finished.

One issue I'm running into is that although the documentation for connectedAndroidTest says that it tests a build on multiple devices simultaneously, what it actually does is build the app then tests it on all connected devices.

In my CI pipeline I desire to build the app in a previous stage, save the build as an artifact, then run tests with that build. Is there a way to use an existing build with connectedAndroidTest so that the task does not need to build the app again needlessly?